# Documenting Qt project using Doxygen

Tags: qt, doxygen

I am trying to document my `Qt` based project using `Doxygen`. It looks like a good way to go. I am able to generate everything ok. I am particularly interested in the usage relations graphs drawn for objects. These shown where an object has references to other objects.

This again works fine where I have a simple pointer to another object such as:

```
OtherClass *myOtherObject;
```

But if I use Qt things like:

```
QPointer <OtherClass> myOtherObject;
```

Or

```
QList <OtherClass*> myOtherObjects;
```

Then these do not show up in the graph.

Is it possible to configure `Doxygen` to understand that these are usage relations as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a partial solution to your problem by using an input filter. With the filter enabled, the diagrams are correct, but the text is incorrect. Example screen shots below.

### Filter

The filter is written in Python, so should work on any platform.

Save this in a file (e.g. qt-filter.py) along with your Doxyfile.

```
import re, sys

PATTERNS = [
    (re.compile(r"QPointer *<(.*)>"), r"\1*"),
    (re.compile(r"QList *<(.*)>"), r"\1")
]

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        prev = None
        while line != prev:
            prev = line
            for regex, repl in PATTERNS:
                line = regex.sub(repl, line)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

### Configuration

In your Doxyfile edit the `FILTER_PATTERNS` line to contain:

```
FILTER_PATTERNS = *.hpp=qt-filter.py
```

### Before Filter

[image: Screenshot of before applying filter]

### After Filter

[image: Screenshot of after applying filter]